# SQL Server: How to obtain the SUM of the top 5 orders by country

Tags: sql-server

This is my first time around here :p

I have SQL Server practice.

Based on the country where `Northwind` customers reside, show the sum of the 5 highest purchase orders by country. The results should be presented in two columns: country, amount

I tried:

```
SELECT 
    vt.ShipCountry, vt.suma
FROM
    (SELECT 
         o.ShipCountry,
         SUM( UnitPrice * Quantity * (1-discount)) as suma,
         RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY SUM(UnitPrice * Quantity * (1-discount)) ORDER BY shipCountry DESC) AS Rank
     FROM 
         orders o 
     JOIN 
         [Order Details] od ON o.OrderID = od.OrderID
     GROUP BY 
         o.ShipCountry) as vt
WHERE 
    Rank <= 5
GROUP BY 
    vt.ShipCOUNTRY, vt.suma
```

but, it retrieves me the sum of all orders per country, only want the top 5 per country

Here's another one, same issue.

```
SELECT 
    ShipCountry, rk, amount
FROM 
    (SELECT  
         o.ShipCountry, 
         SUM(UnitPrice * Quantity * (1-discount)) amount,
         DENSE_RANK() OVER(PARTITION BY o.ShipCountry ORDER BY SUM(UnitPrice * Quantity * (1-discount)) DESC) AS rk
     FROM 
         Orders o 
     JOIN
         [Order Details] od ON o.OrderID = od.OrderID
      GROUP BY 
         o.shipCountry) AS L
 WHERE 
     rk <= 5;
```

The two queries have the same behaviour

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
-- first, sum up the total amount of each order
;WITH OrderDetails AS
(
    SELECT 
        o.OrderID,
        TotalOrderAmount = SUM(UnitPrice * Quantity * (1 - discount))
    FROM 
         orders o 
    INNER JOIN 
         [Order Details] od ON o.OrderID = od.OrderID
    GROUP BY
        o.OrderID
),
-- secondly, join the "ShipCountry" to the order totals,
-- and define a ROW_NUMBER() for each country, based on 
-- total order amount
OrderPerCountry AS
(
    SELECT
        o.ShipCountry,
        od.TotalOrderAmount,
        RowNum = ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY o.ShipCountry ORDER BY od.TotalOrderAmount DESC) 
    FROM 
        OrderDetails od 
    INNER JOIN
        dbo.Orders o ON o.OrderID = od.OrderID
)
SELECT * 
FROM OrderPerCountry
WHERE RowNum <= 5
```

This should do the trick for you - I hope!